# What to do in a topological sort if, after decreasing adjacent node values none are reduced to 0?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, nodes, topological-sort

So my understanding of topological sort is as follows:

- You assign each node an indegree, or number of incoming edges
- You start with the node that has an indegree of 0 and enqueue it
- Once it is queued, you look for adjacent nodes of the queued node and decrease their indegree by 1. If the indegree value of said nodes is 0, then you add it to the queue and repeat steps 2-3 until completion.

However, what if when you decrease the indegree values of the adjacent nodes and none of them resolve to 0? Below is a picture that illustrates my problem

[image: Topological sort problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in step 1, where you did not decrease the indegree of node D. Then, after step 2, both H and D would be added to the queue. It is okay not to get any nodes to 0 indegree in a step, as long as you still have nodes in your queue to go on.

Comment: I think you might be incorrect. I'm actually decreasing the indegrees, not the edge weights.

Comment: @DavidKenyon96 Sorry, you are right, I must have misread the image. I've corrected the answer now.

Comment: Ah, thank you! one more question, if you have two nodes in the queue (meaning two nodes reach 0 indegrees on the same step), which do you decide to do first? or do you do both at the same time?

Edit: looks like both of the queued nodes point to the same node (E) so does that mean that the indegrees of E is decreased by 2 ?

Comment: @DavidKenyon96 It's really not important which one you choose, but you have to go one by one. The topological sort of a DAG is not necessarily unique, so any choice will give a valid result. Traditionally, the algorithm says that you'd use a queue for the nodes, so it would be the first one that you put in there, but, as I said, it's not important.

Comment: Great, you've been very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidKenyon96 No problem. If you want you may accept the answer if you think your question is solved.